# How do I use ESCAPE in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Trying [this answer](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2391/9485.aspx) and not having any luck:

I am using the **SQLite Database browser** (built with 3.3.5 of the SQLite engine) to execute this query:

```
SELECT columnX FROM MyTable

WHERE columnX LIKE  '%\%16'  ESCAPE '\'
```

In column `X`I have a row with the data: `sampledata%167`

I execute the statement and get no data returned but no error either?

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

(SQLite with C API)

Comment: What you're doing looks like an ideal place for a SQL injection attack. Please reconsider this, using parameters instead.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: True, but this is an in house database....

Comment: So? Internal threats are more likely than external.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are missing a `%` from the end of the pattern.

```
'%\%16%'
```

Also backslashes often cause confusion in various programming languages and tools, especially if there is multiple levels of parsing involved before the query gets to the database. To simplify things you could try a different escape character instead:

```
WHERE columnX LIKE '%!%16%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: hmmm same result, it must not like the ESCAPE ? but it shows it does support it? Is it my syntax with quotes, double quotes some combination?

Comment: @ Mark Byers: ahhh, yeah forgot the trailing '%'

Comment: @MarkByers can i escape multiple characters, like ESCAPE '~','@' etc

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data ends in `%167`, but your query only matches things which end in `%16`. You may need to change your query to have a trailing `%` or end with `167` as your data does, depending on your needs.

When I try this in SQLite, it works just fine:

```
sqlite> create table foo (bar text);
sqlite> insert into foo (bar) values ('sampledata%167');
sqlite> select * from foo where bar like '%\%16' escape '\';
sqlite> select * from foo where bar like '%\%167' escape '\';
sampledata%167
```

You may want to try experimenting with this in the SQLite shell, on a simple example table like I show, to see if your problem still exists there.